# How can I use Ubidots for Raspberry pi 3?

Tags: python, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I am using Ubidots to display data from raspberry pi 3. Whenever I try to run ubidots python code in python 3.4.2, it seems that an error occurred.

> > >
> >     Traceback (most recent call last):
> >        File "/home/pi/ubi_test.py", line 1, in 
> >            from ubidots import ApiClient
> >     ImportError : No module named 'ubidots'
> >     >

I have follow all the step for installing python library:

```
$sudo pip install ubidots==1.6.6

$sudo easy_install pip

$sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

Any idea to solve this problem? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHKr8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using python 3 use

> sudo pip3 install

Comment: I write $ sudo pip3 install ubidots==1.6.6, but i got this error.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
 from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name 'IncompleteRead'

Comment: well it works on my mac, but you might try to update the pi, **sudo apt-get update** then try again

Comment: You can should first uninstall pip (sudo apt-get remove pyton3-pip) and then install it again with easy_install (sudo easy_install3 pip).

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple to send http requests to Ubidots API, so I would recommend doing it directly with the requests library, see this tutorial: http://help.ubidots.com/developers/send-data-to-ubidots-using-python-requests

Comment: Links are great, but it what really makes a good answer would be to at least summarize how something explained in the linked page is done. Note that over time links may break.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MQTT to send data to Ubidots. It is very easy. You need just a MQTT client and in a few steps you are ready.
I wrote a tutorial about using MQTT with Ubidots even if it is for Arduino it could be useful for you:
https://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2017/03/how-to-build-an-arduino-mqtt-client.html

You can find the main steps to follow to configure Ubidots and MQTT.